# How do you force Rmarkdown plots to be Square instead of Rectangle?

Tags: r

I have a Generalized Linear Model (GLM) that I'm plotting diagnostics for using the `glm.diag.plots` function in the MASS package. But it tends to plot rectangular instead of square, which is very ugly for publication.

Below is some sample code that shows the problem in an .Rmd file.  In Rstudio, you can just drag the window around until it's square, but not possible in Rmarkdown documents, and I'd like to enforce square manually.
[image]

I checked in the ggplot documentation for ways to enforce square plotting, but could not find anything.  glm.diag.plot() appears to use split.screen(), which doesn't provide any documentation for enforcing aspect ratios, either.

Comment: That doesn't look like ggplot output. You should post the code you are using.

Comment: change the size/aspect ratio of your device `pdf('fig.pdf', height = 6, width = 6)`

Comment: Under the Warnings for `split.screen()`, it says that this function is incompatible with many other basic plotting functions.  You can try to format the entire size and aspect ratio like rawr said, but to have fine control of the plotting area, you may have to look into extracting the plot panels individually and then arrange them manually.

Comment: @Hong Ooi, why would you delete the sample code I included?  Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Your code doesn't produce the graphs shown here. It's easy enough to look up the function itself, especially since it's part of the MASS package which comes with R.

Comment: And also: this is unrelated to ggplot, which is a different framework for producing graphs.

Comment: Yeah, I'm cool with removing ggplot2 as a tag, I can't include the raw data because it's not something I want on the Internet.  Can we find some happy middle ground somehow?

Comment: added some generic code per the oh-so-helpful advice from a superior stack overflow user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@rawr's comment is spot-on; this is a knitr/markdown issue, not glm.diag or ggplot or anything else. All you need to do is specify the desired height and width of the output (in inches, by default) using `fig.width` and `fig.height`.

[image]

Comment: Yup, you're totally right.  I can't believe I didn't put that together.  This works like a champ both inline in Rstudio and also in my .pdf export.  Thanks so much.  This is the answer.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are using `glm.diag.plots` from package `boot` to acquire plots.
You could recreate them using `ggplot` if you wish. Here is an example:

some model:

```
data(anorexia, package = "MASS")

anorex.1 <- glm(Postwt ~ Prewt + Treat + offset(Prewt),
                family = gaussian, data = anorexia)
```

the `glm.diag.plots` output

```
library(boot)
glm.diag.plots(anorex.1)
```

[image]

To create each plot in `ggplot` first get an object from `glm.diag.plots`

```
z <- glm.diag.plots(anorex.1, ret = T)
```

then plot each plot:

```
library(ggplot2)

plot1 <- ggplot(data.frame(x = predict(anorex.1),
                           y = z$res))+
  geom_point(aes(x, y)) +
  xlab("Linear predictor") +
  ylab("Residuals") +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(aspect.ratio=1)

plot2 <- ggplot(data.frame(x = qnorm(ppoints(length(z$rd)))[rank(z$rd)],
                           y = z$rd)) +
  geom_point(aes(x, y)) +
  xlab("Ordered deviance residuals") +
  ylab("Quantiles of standard normal") +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1, lty =2) +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(aspect.ratio=1)

plot3 <- ggplot(data.frame(x = z$h/(1-z$h),
                           y = z$cook)) +
  geom_point(aes(x, y)) +
  xlab("h/(h-1)") +
  ylab("Cook statistic") +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(aspect.ratio=1)

plot4 <- ggplot(data.frame(x = 1:length(z$cook),
                           y = z$cook)) +
  geom_point(aes(x, y)) +
  xlab("Case") +
  ylab("Cook statistic") +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(aspect.ratio=1)
```

then combine them

```
library(cowplot)

plot_grid(plot1, plot2, plot3, plot4, ncol = 2)
```

[image]

Now you can customize  each plot the way you wish.

Comment: This is really great --- thanks.  Forgive me if I'm missing something obvious, but I don't see where the y2 variable is assigned.  Is that a built-in variable to a model or something?

Comment: Good catch. I upadated the answer. Looks like I did not copy all the code to the answer.